# LINUX: How to softlink specific files in all subdirectories

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I want to create soft links (`ln -s`) to `folder2` of all the files that contain `*foo*` in its name, and can be found in some or all the subdirectories of `folder1`.

I've tried it with `for`, `find`, and `find -exec ln`, and a combination of them, but all I get is a broken link named `*foo*` or a link to everything inside `folder1`

Comment: Can you paste the code you have tried?

Comment: Should really be on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: for i in ../[folder1 directory]/*scn*; do ln -s $i; done

This, being in folder2

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming and is better asked on unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With **globstar** at one stroke.

```
shopt -s globstar
cd folder2
ln -s ../folder1/**/*foo* .
```

`cd` is needed for relative links (this applies for below answers that utilizes **find** too). If you want absolute links, do

```
shopt -s globstar
ln -s /where/is/it/folder1/**/*foo* folder2/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're in the target folder you want to create the symbolic link, just use `ln -s <target file>`. The sym link name will be same as the target file.

If you need to do this for several file, use a `for` loop.

Example:

```
$ mkdir folder1 folder2
$ cd folder1
$ touch foo foobar foofoobar foobarfoo bar barfoo barbar
$ ls
bar  barbar  barfoo  foo  foobar  foobarfoo  foofoobar
$ cd ../folder2
$ for i in ../folder1/*foo*; do ln -s $i; done
$ ls -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 abc abc 17 oct.  26 11:57 barfoo -> ../folder1/barfoo
lrwxrwxrwx 1 abc abc 14 oct.  26 11:57 foo -> ../folder1/foo
lrwxrwxrwx 1 abc abc 17 oct.  26 11:57 foobar -> ../folder1/foobar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 abc abc 20 oct.  26 11:57 foobarfoo -> ../folder1/foobarfoo
lrwxrwxrwx 1 abc abc 20 oct.  26 11:57 foofoobar -> ../folder1/foofoobar
```

Comment: Hello, it doesn't work, it only creates a broken file named *foo*. Please consider that the files are in sub-sub...-sub directories in folder1

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
for fileName in `find folder1 -name *foo*`
do
   name1=`basename $fileName`
   ln -sf $fileName folder/$name1
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
for file in `find . -name *foo* -print`
do
    ln -s $file folder2/
done
```

Comment: Same result as applying the code provided by oliv: it doesn't work, it only creates a broken file named foo. Please consider that the files are in sub-sub...-sub directories in folder1

Comment: Can you please paste the error? or Example of actual o/p and expected o/p